# How can I add an entry in a HABTM table in CakePHP using the JQuery Autosuggest onItemSelect event?

Tags: jquery, cakephp, jquery-autocomplete

I'm using the AutoSuggest as a search suggest to add an Item to a Grocerylist(groclist). When a user selects a suggestion it should add the Item to the GroceryList using AJAX, and reload the Items on that Grocery List. I'm using the tutorial found at [Jquery AutoComplete in CakePHP](http://nuts-and-bolts-of-cakephp.com/2008/05/07/jquery-autocomplete-in-cakephp/) to do the AutoComplete, but I'm stuck.

How do I add the association?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#autoComplete").autocomplete("/groceries/items/autoComplete",
{
    minChars: 2,
    cacheLength: 10,
    onItemSelect: selectItem,
    onFindValue: findValue,
    formatItem: formatItem,
    selectFirst: true
});
});
// This is was here
function selectItem(li) {
findValue(li);
}


function addAssociation(li) {

}

function findValue(li) {
if( li == null ) {return alert("No match!");}

// if coming from an AJAX call, let's use the product id as the value
if( !!li.extra ) {var sValue = li.extra[0];}

// otherwise, let's just display the value in the text box
else {var sValue = li.selectValue; }

//alert("The value you selected was: " + sValue);
}

function formatItem(row) {
if(row[1] == undefined) {
    return row[0];
}
else {
    //return row[0] + " (id: " + row[1] + ")"; original displays Cake (id: 1)
    return row[0];
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use an ajax call with a json object. What I mean, is to do an ajax call to an action in cake (regular cake like webpage) but this one will return you a json object. The json object should be used to get information of the data saved, like if there was an error or something like that.

somthing like this :

```
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: url,
    data: param,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
        if (data != null && data.error != null) {
            alert('An error ocurred: '+data.error);
        }
        else {
            yourRefreshFunction();
        }
    },
    error: function(data) {
        try {
            alert('An error ocurred: '+data.error);
        } catch (e) { }
    }
});
```

Hope this helps you :D

EDIT:

In your case would be something like this (remember to change yourRefreshFunction for the real refresh function or after succes function or anything you wanna do after it does the save): 
function selectItem(li) {

```
 //in your cake controller you will receive it as $this->data if you put the name like that
var param = [
    { name: "data[Model][field]", value: findValue(li) }
];
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: url,
    data: param,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
        if (data != null && data.error != null) {
            alert('An error ocurred: '+data.error);
        }
        else {
            yourRefreshFunction();
        }
    },
    error: function(data) {
        try {
            alert('An error ocurred: '+data.error);
        } catch (e) { }
    }
});
}
```

Comment: I'm a bit unsure of how to merge this with my current javascript.

Comment: @Chris I update the answer more less, that is what you need to do